# Remove dynamically added view component

Tags: react-native, dynamic

I have a component that allow user to press on "Add" button to dynamically add View component. I have managed to do the adding but how i can improve the code to remove dynamically added view component?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
View, 
Text, Platform, 
StyleSheet, 
TouchableOpacity, 
Animated, 
ScrollView, 
Image, 
Button 
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<{}>
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this.state = { valueArray: [], disabled: false }

        this.index = 0;

        this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
    }

    addMore = () =>
    {
        this.animatedValue.setValue(0);

        let newlyAddedValue = { index: this.index }

        this.setState({ disabled: true, valueArray: [ ...this.state.valueArray, newlyAddedValue ] }, () =>
        {
            Animated.timing(
                this.animatedValue,
                {
                    toValue: 1,
                    duration: 500,
                    useNativeDriver: true
                }
            ).start(() =>
            {
                this.index = this.index + 1;
                this.setState({ disabled: false });
            }); 
        });              
    }

    render()
    {
        const animationValue = this.animatedValue.interpolate(
        {
            inputRange: [ 0, 1 ],
            outputRange: [ -59, 0 ]
        });

        let newArray = this.state.valueArray.map(( item, key ) =>
        {
            if(( key ) == this.index)
            {
                return(
                    <Animated.View key = { key } style = {[ styles.viewHolder, { opacity: this.animatedValue, transform: [{ translateY: animationValue }] }]}>
                        <Text style = {styles.text}>Row { item.index }</Text>
                        <Button style={styles.button}>
                          <Text style = {styles.text}>Remove</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </Animated.View>
                );
            }
            else
            {
                return(
                    <View key = { key } style = { styles.viewHolder }>
                        <Text style = { styles.text }>Row { item.index }</Text>
                        <Button style={styles.button}>
                          <Text style = {styles.text}>Remove</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                );
            }
        });

        return(
            <View style = { styles.container }>
                <ScrollView contentContainerStyle = { this.scrollViewStyle }>
                    <View style = {{ flex: 1, padding: 4 }}>
                    {
                        newArray
                    }
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>

                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity = { 0.8 } style = { styles.btn } disabled = { this.state.disabled } onPress = { this.addMore }>
                    <Image source = { require('./assets/add.png') } style = { styles.btnImage }/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove it from the this.state.valueArray. If you know which index you want to remove you can do it as;

```
removeItem = (index) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    valueArray: prevState.valueArray.splice(index, 1),
  }));
}
```

Here, you are basically taking an index, create a new array from the previous one without said index and update the state.

Comment: this is not working up to mark... when I delete the row and after that add again than it will not work properly ... is there any other solution ?

Comment: You need to be more specific. He has a chunk of code attached to his question, your implementation may differ.